# How to find the Eigen version that Tensorflow downloads?

Tags: tensorflow, eigen, bazel

I am trying to figure out what Eigen version is my Tensorflow using. I can see that Bazel downloads Eigen based on a hashed value inside `tensorflow/workspace.bzl` file. In that file there are two values:

`eigen_version = "6d4cd6e5cdd9"`

`eigen_sha256 = "c8df78734ba9b402b94586be5eda78ee75e0244a99e8ae4183785710c44eb93f"`.

However, I don't know how to map them to the correct Eigen version.

Comment: Did you find the version?

Comment: I found it via Method 1, mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same needs. What I do:

**Method 1**: (if already download eigen during tf-build)
check `bazel-tensorflow-xxx/external/eigen_archive/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h`. For example:

```
cat bazel-tensorflow-r1.3/external/eigen_archive/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h | grep -i version
\#define EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION 3<br/>
\#define EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION 3<br/>
\#define EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION 90<br/>
```

**Method 2**:

download & unzip the eigen archive (such as http://mirror.bazel.build/bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/f3a22f35b044.tar.gz) , and check the same header file.

Answer (score 1):

The hash `6d4cd6e5cdd9` looks like it would correspond to [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/6d4cd6e5cdd9c750b10cc4c6a374e4c513b267ed). That would appear to be in the dev branch. The version number in Macros.h would be 3.2.93 (a bit before 3.3rc1).

Comment: So, there's no way to find the version inside the Tensorflow install directory itself?

Comment: Is there a directory for Eigen?

Comment: Look for Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h. Open it in your favorite editor. It's near the top.

Comment: Under `tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/Eigen` I see:
`Cholesky  Core  Eigenvalues  LU  QR  SVD` and under `tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/` I see a few dir including these: `FixedPointTypes.h  MatMatProductAVX2.h  MatMatProduct.h  MatMatProductNEON.h  MatVecProduct.h  PacketMathAVX2.h  TypeCastingAVX2.h Activations.h  Attention.h  BackwardCuboidConvolutions.h  BackwardSpatialConvolutions.h  CuboidConvolution.h  Patch3d.h  Pooling.h  SoftMax.h  SpatialConvolutions.h  TensorConvolutionByFFT.h`

Comment: funny thing is that I don't have any Macros.h header under my tensorflow root directory!